# fatal: open /dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory

Tags: git, bash, repository, sourcetree

I am new here and i will try to explain my question kindly ignore any mistakes.

I am using `git` version `git-2.8.2`
It worked fine for one day then this problem occurs.
I am using `gcloud` repository.
First I tried gcloud clone command then this error occurs
[image]

Then to make sure `git` is there I tired git command then this error occurs[image]

Then I double check by opening `git Bash` but same error was there too.
[image]

I tried reinstalling changing directory. but nothing works.

Comment: it is a well reproducible problem in linux too. inside chroot'ed tree git is returning similar error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem accidentally. I would like to share it with everyone.
It was not a problem of git or gcloud or source tree.

Actually I have forcefully stooped windows update from installing which causes this problem.
Now when I install windows updates again this problem is fixed now.
Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 29):

I face the same problem after I try to avoid memory leak in Windows 10. If you happened to change the *regedit* like me, just type *regedit* in the search then go to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> ControlSet001 -> Services -> Null

change the value of Start to 1.

Comment: This also requires a reboot. ;) Solved the issue for me.

Comment: you saved the day

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally bumped into the same problem when I was sorting out the services running on my computer with Windows 10.

> fatal: open /dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory

The reason was that I deleted the service named `'Null'` that had no description as I thought that was a virus service.

[image]

Thus, when I found my `git` unable to operate, I reckoned the deleted service.
According to a solution provided on some site I tried to run the service again using `cmd.exe`

```
sc config Null start= system
sc start Null
```

but it said the service hadn't been existed in the list.
Thankfully, there are some kind [folks](http://revertservice.com/10/null/) who shares the information of the default services running on Windows 10 and the [description](https://superuser.com/questions/287947/what-is-type-on-a-service) necessary for the successful bringing back the service.

So as to get the service back in the list:

1. press `Win + R`
2. type `regedit`
3. go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services` section
4. Create `Null` folder and all the params it needs.

[image]

5. Restart your computer.
6. Now you got your Null service back and your git back as well.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Omg I kept getting the same null directory not found problem when I tried to use OpenSSH. The sc config Null start= system; sc start Null; worked like a charm. Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 2):

the similar situation in chrooted linux tree is fixable following way:

cd inside the folder where you are preparing the chroot dir, then

`mount -o bind /dev dev/`

then only chroot inside

Answer (score 0):

I had this weird bug just now. I went back a dir and tried git init, it worked there.
I re-ran zsh and tried again in the dir it errored in originally and it worked. *shrugs*