# Why I am facing this error "fatal: could not open '/dev/null' for reading and writing: No such file or directory" when I run "git --version"?

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I was trying to install Git Bash on my Windows 10. But during installation, I got the following error:

> Unable to set system config "diff.astextplain.textconv":="astextplain": exit code 128
> stderr:
> fatal: could not open '/dev/null' for reading and writing: No such file or directory" and many more errors(almost 10 more).

But it was installed.

Then I tried to run `git --version` on the command prompt, and I got

> "fatal: could not open '/dev/null' for reading and writing: No such file or directory"

I tried to solve this by changing the value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> ControlSet001 -> Services -> Null
```

to 1 based on this [Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069502/fatal-open-dev-null-or-dup-failed-no-such-file-or-directory). But the value was already 1. So I did not make any changes.

I do not know how to solve this issue. I did install the Git Bash 20 days ago and that time it has no issue. I don't know what happened 5 days ago. Now I am facing this error. I need a solution how to sovle this error and I use Git Bash properly.

Comment: You can just download it from here and install it, this way the entire setup is done for you https://gitforwindows.org/.

Comment: tried and same issue.

Comment: Not as a solution, but rather as proposition: you could try using wsl2 instead of git-bash.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a null.sys file in your divers. It could be that the null driver is not functioning. In my case it did not exist.

Go to C:> windows> system 32 > drivers > null.sys

If you do have it try uninstalling and reinstalling otherwise download it and add it to the "drivers" directory(not recommended).

For me, I copied the file(null.sys) from another system and pasted it in my drivers. You then run the commands `sc start Null` and `sc query Null` to check the status.

Try installing Git now, it would hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

Push Win + R, type 'regedit', goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Null
find 'Start' option and set value to 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).